# Angular HttpClient Service only returning responses with a statuscode of 200

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a login component that calls an http client service which sends a request to my server to try to log in. If the credentials I enter are valid everything works, but whenever I enter wrong credentials my service apparently doesnt return anything at all.

This is the method that gets called when you click login:

```
  submit(){
    this.auth.tryLogin(this.form.getRawValue())
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      if(res.status == 200){
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      }
      else{
        alert(res.status)
      }
    })
  }
```

and here is the code for the service

```
  tryLogin(data : any) : Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.server + environment.routes.authRoutes.login, data, {
      withCredentials: true,
      observe: 'response'
    })
  }
```

Whenever I enter the correct credentials everythign works fine, the response gets logged to the console and I get redirected to my homepage:
[image]

But when I enter the wrong password/username it doesnt alert the status code and I have no idea why
[image]

Am I using the http client wrong, does it throw an exception when it recieves an error code in he respose? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation it's correct but it's going to work only for success case.

If you look at `Observable` sign, you can see that has some parameter:

```
const observer = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};
```

So in your case you have to:

```
submit(){
  this.auth.tryLogin(this.form.getRawValue())
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status == 200) {
        this.router.navigate(['/'])
      }
      else {
        alert(res.status)
      }
    },
    err => alert(err)
  );
}
```

For more information you can follow [Angular handling error](https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors)

Comment: Thank you! If I userstand what you said correctly, this means that the httpClient throws an error whenever it recieves a response that doesnt have a 2xx status, right? Would the err object in this case contain the http response?

Comment: Correct, you'll get an `HttpErrorResponse` class (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)